# Parent and Child object in SimpleRepository

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3, simplerepository

How would it work in Subsonic's SimpleReporitory if I wanted to be able to have a 1 to many relationship between objects?

Would I have to create a bridge object and then build my parent object at runtime, or is this support built in?

What I am looking for is the folowing:

Adam's Example Shop...

```
Public Class Shop

    Private m_id As Integer
    Private m_Name As String
    Private m_Employees As List(Of Employee)

    Public Property Id() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_id
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            m_id = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return m_Name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_Name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Employees() As List(Of Employee)
        Get
            Return m_Employees
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of Employee))
            m_Employees = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class

Public Class Employee

    Private m_id As Integer
    Private m_Name As String

    Public Property Id() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_id
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            m_id = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return m_Name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_Name = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Main bits:

```
        Dim repo As New SimpleRepository("SubSonicObjectTest", SimpleRepositoryOptions.RunMigrations)

        Dim emplyee1 As New Employee
        emplyee1.Name = "Martin"
        Dim emplyee2 As New Employee
        emplyee2.Name = "Adam"

        Dim shop As New Shop
        shop.Name = "Sub Sonic Store"

        shop.Employees = New List(Of Employee)
        shop.Employees.Add(emplyee1)
        shop.Employees.Add(emplyee2)

        repo.Add(Of Shop)(shop)
```

I think this should create 3 tables:

Shops
Employees
ShopsToEmployees (or some other naming convention)

But I only get a Channels table!

Comment: +1.  Good question.  I can't believe nobody voted this up before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm updating the SimpleRepo stuff currently to automatically create joined tables based on collections. Not easy to determine many/many vs 1/many - but I have some ideas :).

Comment: Fantastic Rob :) I'll wait for the new version

Comment: I'd love to see this too.  Fluent NHibernate is the only option I'm aware of right now that does this, (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610362/subsonic-can-anyone-provide-an-example-of-using-subsonic-to-persist-a-list-arra/1634084#1634084) but it looks complicated.  The Subsonic approach is bound to be much simpler, based on my (admittedly limited) experience.

Comment: I'm still the only one working on it - It's lonely out here. So no - no idea when.

Comment: Rob, is this feature in a fork or branch somewhere I could try?

Answer (score 3):

To create a one to many relationship you just have to create the object model, SubSonic should do the rest for you e.g.

```
public class Shop
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public String Name { get; set; }
  public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT: This should generate two tables when you run a migration not 3. The 3 three tables you describe in your question would represent a many to many relationship. Also in your example you're not saving your Employees, SubSonic does not cascade saves so you'll need to save your Shop then add the Employees to it and BatchSave the Employees.

Comment: I believe that your example if of a one-to-one relationship. I have updated my question with a sample object model for one-to-many...

Comment: Sorry typo in my example, fixed now.

Comment: Also I think you'll need more than just a single Id in your Content class, try adding another property to it

Comment: Sory Adam, on testing I figured that out :).. I still do not get a Content table :(

Comment: You're not saving your employees, this probably means SubSonic never runs the migration for that table, I've added some more info to my answer too.

Comment: Thats the answer I was looking for Adam, thanks... I was hoping that it would cascade... but it is not a deal breaker :)